# SAML Identity Provider with Java

Tags: saml

I have been tasked to implement SAML into our web application.

What I would like to do is develop a proof of concept using our web application (Service Provider) and a identity provider.

What is the simplest and basic Identity Provider to install for a proof of concept?

Comment: Does it have to be inside the application or can it be a standalone application?

Comment: I would assume standalone.  I have read the papers from OASIS and understand the interactions of SAML, however now I need something that I can interact with from my web site.  I have tried installing Shibbeloth and AD FDS with varying issues.  It would be ideal to tie the Idp to ldap or another directory service, but honestly all I need is a simple Idp that I could add users to and interact with from my web application.

Comment: I do want it to be locally installed because my web application is not exposed outside of our network.

Comment: Unfortunately "Simple" and "SAML" don't often go together.  This is a publicly available saml2 testbed: https://www.testshib.org/

Comment: Try http://simplesamlphp.org/. There isn't really a simple SAML STS because the SAML protocol is complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ForgeRock's OpenAM solution. It is also Java based.

http://forgerock.com/products/open-identity-stack/openam/

As others wrote, SAML is not so plug and play game.